# NextJs with React + Unable to update the parent state value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, rxjs, trpc

I am new in NextJS and using the NextJs with React. So I am fetching the users list using trpc with useQuery.

Then I am filter users lists based on user name. I have added the sample code but I have more logic in that.

In below code when I click the button I am passing the username like "user1", In parent component(Users.tsx) the method updateFilter triggered and getting the value of user.In this method I am trying to set the setUsersData values with object of users. I am getting the error. Can someone help me to fix the issue.

Users.tsx

```
const Page = () => {    
    const users = trpc.users.getUsersSummary.useQuery(
        {},
        {
            onError(err) {
                console.log('Failed to retrieve users summary')
            },
        },
    );
    const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState(users);

    const filteredLists = (username: string) => {       
        return users?.data?.users.filter((user: any) =>{
            user.name === username;
        });
    }

    const updateFilter = (username: string) => {
        const getFilterQuery = filteredLists(username);

        setUsersData(current => {
            const data = {...current.data};
            data.users = getFilterQuery;
            return {...current, data};          
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <UserList setUserType={updateFilter} usersSummary={usersData.data} />
        </div>
    )

}
```

Userslists.tsx

```
// Global
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const UserList = ({ usersSummary, setUserType }: UserFilterPropTypes) => {
    const items = usersSummary?.users

    const handleChange = () => {
        setUserType("user1")
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <button onclick= { handleChange()> Filter < /button>
        //Iterating the data
        < /div>
    )
}
```

Json getting from response:

```
[
    {
        "result": {
            "data": {
                "json": {
                    "totalUsers": 40,
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "name": "user1",
                            "status": "Active"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "user2",
                            "status": "De Active"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "user3",
                            "status": "Active"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "user4",
                            "status": "De Active"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "user5",
                            "status": "Active"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        
        }
    }
]
```

Error Details:

Argument of type '(current: (QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Error ::: Argument of type '(current: (QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult .. is not assignable to type '(prevState: (QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `<button onclick= { handleChange()> Filter < /button>` code. The `onclick` handler has to be `onclick={handleChange}`

That way the `handleChange` will be triggered when the onclick event happen. The way you have it now, it executes the `handleChange` method at the time you declare the component and that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your code ,inside your Page component
the following piece of code ,consider usersData as result return by useQuery which is QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult

```
const users = trpc.users.getUsersSummary.useQuery(
{},
{
    onError(err) {
        console.log('Failed to retrieve users summary')
    },
});
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState(users);`
```

Now when you click on button updateFilter is called( nahuelhds also mention syntax error please check that),Which make call to filteredLists which returns an array,So you are basically trying to assign an array
to QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult.

To fix this,Instead of assigning QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult to usersData you should first make an array and then store array in state.
You should just save the filterQueryStr as a state instead of store  filtered array inside state .
consider the below code.

```
const Page = () => {    
const users = trpc.users.getUsersSummary.useQuery(
    {},
    {
        onError(err) {
            console.log('Failed to retrieve users summary')
        },
    },
);
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);
const [filterQuery,setFilterQuery]=useState('')

//when query response change
useEffect(()=>{
    //you can use shorthand syntax like users?.data?.users
    if(users && users.data && Array.isArray(users.data.users)){
        setUsersData(users.data.users)
    }
},[users])

const filteredLists = useMemo((username: string) => {       
    if(filterQuery==='')return  usersData
    return usersData.filter((user: any) =>{
        //you can also try user.name.includes(filterQuery) for short keywords
        return user.name === filterQuery;
    });
},[filterQuery,usersData])

//updateFilter will only update filterQuery string, you can directly pass setFilterQuery to child component
const updateFilter = useCallBack((username: string) => {
    setFilterQuery(username)
});

return (
    <div>
        <UserList setUserType={updateFilter} usersSummary={filteredLists}     />
    </div>
)
  }
```

I Hope this will help.

Comment: Error:   React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?

Comment: Yes, that's my bad,you should pass empty array as a dependency.